# Spring data JPA with multiple parameters which may be null

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA data repository to form a query on number of parameters which may/may not be null.

I used the following repository class to query based on these three parameters. **employee,startDate and endDate**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeReportRepo extends JpaRepository<EmployeeReport, Long>{
    public EmployeeReport findFirstByEmployeeAndDate(Employee employee , Date date);
    public List<EmployeeReport> findByEmployeeAndDateFilter(Employee employee, Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

Following is the named query :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EmployeeReport.findByEmployeeAndDateFilter", query = "SELECT e FROM employee_report e WHERE e.employee="
        + "?1" + " and e.date >=" + "?2" + " and e.date<=" + "?3")
```

But the issue is these parameters may be null in which case my query will fail. How do you I go about this. One solution could be to create multiple queries to facilitate each combination of null conditions but it is not conclusive. Any suggestions what else can I use ?

Comment: That's why the JPA Criteria API exists. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html. There are alternatives: QueryDSL, or even dynamically composed JPQL.

Comment: @JBNizet QueryDSL was what I was thinking of using.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I suggest you to give up the interface repository and make a customised repository using JavaEE EntityManager.

You can handle many cases in the repository.
Such as in your case, null parameters can be handled by just add a if clause.
And, for further usage, you can add a sort order in it.

Hope this can help you.